# Unshare a folder on Windows with Linux subsystem

Tags: linux, windows, directory, shared, subsystem

I have just started using the Windows 11 Linux subsystem. In getting going I did all sorts of things that I cannot remember with the goal of sharing files between Windows and Ubuntu. I can now do this, but my explorations have left an irritating residue (see picture). How this "shared folder" got there is wholly mysterious to me, especially since the quoted matter in fact references not a folder but a file. Does anyone have an idea how I can "unshare" it? The file is unimportant and can be deleted from both file systems.
[image: Windows Ubuntu terminal]

Answer (score 0):

The "SharedFolder" is an empty folder created somehow by Windows. I deleted it. The long purple file was also created by Windows somehow and I deleted it too. How the stuff got there I do not know. There is (some) documentation on the relation between the two file systems at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/filesystems